# do while loop Java

Tags: java, loops, do-while

So I am pretty much a newbie to coding and am busy playing around with "do while loops", my code is probably terrible and there are most likely a 1000 better ways to do what I am trying to do but anyways.

I'm trying to use main method and then two other methods (for practice purposes) to ask the user to chose a number between 1 and 10 then if they want to try again.

I get the code to run up until it asks the user to enter yes/no but then the code stops running and i cant figure out why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    chooseNum();

}

public static boolean chooseNum() {
    int number = 4;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a number 1 to 10");
        int userNum = in.nextInt();
        if (number == userNum) {
            System.out.println("You chose the correct number!");
            return tryAgain();
        } else if (number != userNum) {
            System.out.println("You chose the incorrect number!");
            return tryAgain();
        } else
            System.out.println("invalid Response");
    }
    while (false);
    return false;
}

public static boolean tryAgain(){

        System.out.println("Try again? yes/no");
        String response = in.nextLine();
        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            return chooseNum();
        }else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
            return false;
    }else
        return false;
    }
}
```

and my output is as follows:

```
Enter a number 1 to 10
1
You chose the incorrect number!
Try again? yes/no

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I cant seem to get it any further in order for me to input yes or no.

I know this is basic and I most likely look pathetic but any help will be appreciated.

Maybe another rookie can get their chance at helping someone out:)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Well it should give me the option to input "yes" or "no". If yes, it runs the loop again and i chose another number, if NO then it ends the code.

Comment: Try `do {...} while (true)` instead of `...while(false)`.

Comment: "while(false)" is literally telling the loop to stop looping. You need to replace it with some actual condition to check for.

Comment: Actually, while(false) is correct here, because it is looping with recursion, not the while loop. (PS, don't use recursion as a while loop!)

Comment: You should change the while loop to `while(tryAgain())`, and don't call chooseNum in tryAgain

Comment: `while (false)` is a NOP (No Operation) no need to use it at all

Comment: As others hinted, you have `chooseNum` calling `tryAgain` and `tryAgain` calling `chooseNum`. That is crazy tangled. It's even worse that it happens inside a loop, let alone a loop that cannot loop.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `next()` instead of `nextLine()` because when you are reading int and adding `\n` to submit the values. Scanner is treating this as the input. `next()` should ignore previously entered `\n` and will take input as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the nextLine error by just making a new instance of the scanner inside the methods. I made edits to your code by declaring a new Scanner in chooseNum and tryAgain, which would avoid the issue caused by buffered input. I hope this helps.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dowhile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        chooseNum();
    }

    public static boolean chooseNum() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = 4;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a number 1 to 10");
            int userNum = in.nextInt();
            if (number == userNum) {
                System.out.println("You chose the correct number!");
                return tryAgain();
            } else if (number != userNum) {
                System.out.println("You chose the incorrect number!");
                return tryAgain();
            } else
                System.out.println("invalid Response");
        }
        while (false);
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean tryAgain(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Try again? yes/no");
        String response = in.nextLine();
        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            return chooseNum();
        }else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
            return false;
        }else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the line `return tryAgain();`, the `chooseNum()` method ends. That's the result of a return statement.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, the "nextLine" gotcha...

When you enter the the 1, STDIN contains `1\n\r`. When you call nextInt(), it pops the 1 leaving `\n\r` in the STDIN stream. Now when it calls nextLine() to get the next input, it reads to the next `\n\r`, and returns an empty string since `\n\r` still contaminates the IN stream. If you use next() instead, it will ignore the `\n\r` (and any other whitespace) and give you the next word from STDIN. (You can also just call nextLine() twice to clear the `\n\r` from the nextInt call)

And this is the correct way to use the do-while for this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    chooseNum();
}

public static void chooseNum() {
    int number = 4;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a number 1 to 10");
        int userNum = in.nextInt();
        if (number == userNum) {
            System.out.println("You chose the correct number!");
        } else if (number != userNum) {
            System.out.println("You chose the incorrect number!");
        } else
            System.out.println("invalid Response");
    }
    while (tryAgain());
}

public static boolean tryAgain(){
    do {
        System.out.println("Try again? yes/no");
        String response = in.nextLine();
        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            return true;
        }else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
            return false;
        }else
            System.out.println("Invalid response.");
        }
    } while(true);
}
```